# Not draw Multiple ChromiumWebBrowser C#

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

i trying draw 5 chromiumWebBrowsers of the hand CefSharp.dll but not working good, some loads work good another not, i working  at one desktop application and i trying draw 5 chromiumWebBrowser in only one winform

For every ChromiumWebBrowser, i created one instance and called with his diferent HTML file, for every Browser.Load(HTML), Browser1.Load(HTML2).....

I belive that are the EventArgs of method, when i invoke the method call, i create one by one the **Browser.LOAD** ChromiumWebBrowser..

My scope is draw 5 **VIWERS of FORGE** and set the models in this viewers.

I hope that someone i help me or say what is my error.

Thanks

[image: Form load ChromiumWebBrowsers]

Here, Create instances ChromiumWebBrowsers....

```
 public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser2;
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser3;

    #region Chromium
    public void InitBrowser()
    {

        if (Cef.IsInitialized != true)
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:////////HTML/Viewer.html");

            browser.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            browser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            browser.Name = "webBrowser1";
            browser.TabIndex = 1;
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox1.Controls.Add(browser);


            browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:////////HTML/Viewer-1.html");

            browser2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            browser2.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            browser2.Name = "webBrowser2";
            browser2.TabIndex = 1;
            browser2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox2.Controls.Add(browser2);
}
            else
            {
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:////////HTML/Viewer.html");
            browser.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            browser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            browser.Name = "webBrowser1";
            browser.TabIndex = 1;
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox1.Controls.Add(browser);

            browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:////////HTML/Viewer-1.html");

            browser2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            browser2.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            browser2.Name = "webBrowser2";
            browser2.TabIndex = 1;
            browser2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           pictureBox2.Controls.Add(browser2);
}
```

Here, in Form_Load, i load and call API´s and set data for that draw in the **Chromium**...

```
 private void ForgeVisorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GlobalVar.GlobalVars = modelo1.Text;
        var urnModel = GetModelsInfo.CompareModelsBussiness(GlobalVar.GlobalVars);
        var urnbase64 = GetModelsInfo.GetUrnModels(urnModel);
        GetModelsInfo.Authenticate_Token();

        if (urnbase64 != null)
        {
            browser.Load(string.Format("file:///////HTML/Viewer.html?URN={0}&Token={1}", urnbase64, GlobalVar.AccesTokenForge));
        }


        GlobalVar.GlobalVars = modelo2.Text;
        var urnModel2 = GetModelsInfo.CompareModelsBussiness(GlobalVar.GlobalVars);
        var urnbase = GetModelsInfo.GetUrnModels(urnModel2);
        GetModelsInfo.Authenticate_Token();

        if (urnbase != null)
        {
            browser2.Load(string.Format("file:///////HTML/Viewer-1.html?URN={0}&Token={1}", urnbase, GlobalVar.AccesTokenForge));
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is common about the loads that dont work?

Comment: I have been investigating and I found rather that it is a problem of ** CefSharp **, the problem that happens to me is not that sometimes it loads me and sometimes not, if I do debug it works but if I let run free the load does not work in the ** ChromiumWebBrowser **

In some versions of CefSharp the problem is proxy but I don't know how to verify that.

I am using VS 2019 and the latest version of CefSharp

Comment: Please specify the exact version you are using. Using the File scheme is nothing but trouble see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#file-uri-file I suggest https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler